# Show that $ac = bcq + rc$

Tags: abstract-algebra

So my text book says
"Let $a$ be any integer and let $b$ and $c$ be positive integers. Suppose that when $a$ is divided by $b$, the quotient is $q$ and the remainder is $r$, so that ($a = bq +r$) and $0 \le r < b$.

If $ac$ is divided by $bc$, show that the quotient q and the remainder is $rc$."

My solution is as follows:

$ac=bcq+rc$ and $0 \le r < b$

We assume that $0 \le rc < bc$, since multiplying by $|c|$ does not change them.

$ac = bcq + rc$

$ac = (bc)q + (rc)$

Then by the division algorithm $q$ and $rc$ are the unique quotient and remainder when $ac$ is divided by $bc$.

but... Dividing by $bc$ gives us:

$ac/bc = bcq/bc + rc/bc$

$a/b = q + r/b$

$a = bq + r$

So where is $rc$ now?

Comment: What do you mean by "where is $rc$ now"? I don't see any contradiction in what you wrote.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Check https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for how to typeset your questions in TeX. Since $c$ is a positive integer you don't need the absolute value $|c|$, in fact stating that makes no sense anyway as your inequality is $0 \le rc < bc$, not $0 \le r|c| < b|c|$. As to where $rc$ is, you lose $c$ when you divide by $bc$ as it's a common factor in $ac=bcq+rc$. Then you multiply through by $b$ again to regain $a=bq+r$. Probably best to number your equations so you can refer to them in your proof..

Answer (score 1):

The statement that $a=bq+r$ means that $b|(a-r)$ (note that dividing gives $a/b=q+r/b$).

Note that this means
$$ac-rc=(a-r)c=(bq)c.$$
Therefore,
$ac=(bq)c+rc=(bc)q+rc$. Since $0\leq r<b$, we have $0\leq rc<bc$. By uniqueness, the quotient and remainder when dividing $ac$ by $bc$ is $q$ and $rc$, respectively.

Comment: But dividing $ 0 \leq rc < bc$ through by bc  and multiplying by b would leave us with $ 0 \leq r < b$? That's what I don't get.

Comment: Dividing by $bc$ and then multiplying by $b$ is the same as dividing by $c$. Look, $0\leq r/b<1$, right? So, if you write the decimal expansion for $a/b=q+r/b$, the $r/b$ term is the decimal part. Is this what is confusing you?